# ComponentArt and Ajax Toolkit

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, componentart

I'm using ComponentArt MultiPage control in my application. I'm also using AjaxControl Toolkit's ModalPopUpExtender control. I get the javascript error "Sys.UI.DOMEevnt is null or not an object". I noticed that if I have the ScriptManager in the same page as any ComponentArt control, I get this error. Can someone please suggest me a solution? I'm using ComponentArt 2008.2 and latest version of Ajax Toolkit and .NET Framework 3.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most reports of this problem are related to having references to older MS AJAX DLLs. It could also be a bad ComponentArt install. See the thread at [the CA forum](http://www.componentart.com/community/forums/p/25346/26977.aspx#26977) another thread at [the Iron Speed forum](http://sjc.ironspeed.com/post?id=1902056)  for more information.